# Why same code with -Ofast flag taking too long in g++

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, clang++

I have implemented [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find prime numbers in C++. 
This is my code which

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
const int SZ = 12345678;
vector<int> prime;

bool sieve() {
    bitset<SZ> is_prime;
    int limit = int(1e6) + 7;
    for(int i = 3; i < limit; i += 2) {
        if(!is_prime[i]) {
            prime.push_back(i);
            for(int j = i + i; j < limit; j += i)
                is_prime[j] = true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void) {

    clock_t start = clock();
    sieve();
    long long count = 0;
    for(auto it = prime.begin(); it != prime.end(); ++it)
        ++count;
    cout << count << endl;
    clock_t end = clock();

    cout << "Time taken: " << (double)(end - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I am running above code with `clang++-3.6 main.cpp -Ofast -std=c++14` then compiled binary is taking around 6 seconds to run while same code when compiled with `g++ main.cpp -Ofast -std=c++14` compiled binary is taking around 54 seconds to run.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It appears that the `bitset` is the culprit. Using an array of `bool`s instead [cuts the runtime down drastically](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a51152b0e86b3b95).

Comment: `is_prime[i] = true;` are you sure you mean't `i`?

Comment: @kfsone that was a typo sorry

Comment: @T.C. I think that's a red herring. It's true that `vector<char>` or an array of bools will make it run faster, that happens in both compilers. The crux here is that clang is also using libstdc++ so it's a compiler rather than a library issue.

Comment: `j += 2` in the inner loop looks wrong.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Yes, it's clearly a compiler issue. But it's the compiler's handling of the bitset operation that is at issue.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce the timing discrepancy with your modified code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fd09e805cc4aa2e).

Comment: The bitset should actually be named `is_composite`?  (Since it is false for primes)